# Stop checking the price after Take profit or stop loss is reached, Custom function on Google sheet with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hope there is someone to help me as I just surrender. I have a google sheet which is populated by static format emails related to trading signals. I found here a script to get the new emails into this sheet. These signals have the following format:

DateAndTime, Market, EntryType, EntryRate, TakeProfit1, TakeProfit2, StopLoss, LiveResult, LiveRate, PL
30/03/2020 , EURUSD, BUY      , 1.1025    , 1.1055    , 1.1095     , 1.1000  , -10       , 1.1015  , ??

With importjson, I get the live rates of all pairs an I compare them with the entry to generate the live result.

I need a custom function, that compares the live rate with TP2 and Stop loss and tells me which one is reached but, once one of the conditions is met I want the function to stop checking and just leave the value "hit tp" or "hit SL" in the PL cell.

I tried with if, with, query, with custom function (very basic because I am not a programmer), with importance, and also I tried to assign a unique value to another cell and then use the IF statement to that cell but none of them worked. Once the price changes, the PL cell changes always the value in it.

I tried to study a little code, but I continue to get error over and over. It is 3 months trying to get this done without getting a result. I am not a programmer but I could arrange to get the rates, update the importjson every minute, delete the old emails, and everything needed using scripts found here.

at this stage I declare myself totally incapable to proceed. Any help would be absolutely appreciated

This is my function. But it is nothing else than a normal IF

```
function IFUNTIL(dir,target2, stop, price) {

var result;
var count = 0;

      if (dir === "BUY" && count == 0){

          switch (true)
                {
                 case (price > target2):
                    result = "TP2 HIT";
                    count++;
                    break;

                 case (price < stop):
                    result = "STOP HIT";
                    count++;
                    break;
                 default:
                   result = "Running";
                   count =  0;
                   break;
                 }  

        } else

        if (dir === "SELL" && count == 0) {

              switch (true)
                {
                 case (price < target2):
                    result = "TP2 HIT";
                    count++;
                    break;
                 case (price > stop):
                    result = "STOP HIT";
                    count++;
                    break;
                  default:
                   result = "Running";
                   count =  0;
                   break;
                 }  
              }
```

return result;
 }

Comment: Hi ! If possible, could you please share a sample of your spreadsheet (without any sensitive data) so that it is easier to understand what you are trying to achive? Also, could you clarify to me this? : you are getting successfully the ```live rate``` but your issue is that you do not know how to compare it with ```TP2``` and ```Stop Loss``` and specially how to stop it from refreshing. Am I right?

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Below you find the link of the spreadsheet. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRxuBUuJuKZHwioO0VhXybTPfSzHz8RQmGGr4HUdBQvWHrf7rja1mrAaQJ4co04WNdfuEEJaNdv1x9B/pubhtml.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. 

Below you find the link of the spreadsheet. 

In the raw sheet, a script appends the new signals. In sheet2 I split the signal text and add the result column where I compare price from MRates with TP and SL.

Whatever is the first target reached, I want the custom function to stamp a value TP HIT or SL HIT (which ever is the first target to be reached) and stop comparing the price with tp and sl for that signal.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRxuBUuJuKZHwioO0VhXybTPfSzHz8RQmGGr4HUdBQvWHrf7rja1mrAaQJ4co04WNdfuEEJaNdv1x9B/pubhtml.

Comment: Actually I can compare it with an if function, but when the rate changes, the result will change as I don't know how to make it stop comparing. The if function will generate true or false result every time the price of that symbol changes.

For example. the price reaches TP then turns back and reaches SL. It will first writ TP hit then it will write SL hit. Once I open the doc I will never know which one has actually been hit first!

Comment: Hi! How about trying the following? : Change your main function to be an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) (you can easily do thi changing its name to ```onEdit()```). Then, under your ```if``` statements, add a functionallity where you set the values of a couple of columns to 1. if it was TP2 or SL what got hit and 2. the time this change happened. **This will let you keep track of all the changes that happened and when they did.**  Let me know if that worked or if you need more info about how to achieve this :D

Answer (score 0):

Custom functions or any  spreadsheet function cannot be used for limited functionality. Use [time driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) with [`setValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#setValues(Object))

Comment: thank you for your answer!  I was thinking about a script that searches for blank cells on Result column and as long as it finds a blank cell, it looks if there is a signal on the left. If the signal exists then compares the actual price from MRates for that symbol with its TP and SL. If it is greater or lower, according to the type of signal, it assigns a value to the cell in column Result and at the next time-driven check, it goes over that row as there is already a value in it.

I can set it to run every minute with the time-driven trigger, but when it comes to write the script, I am out!

Comment: This is why I came here to ask help because independently from how long I have been searching for that, till now I couldn't find a solution as I did for the script that reads my email, or the one that gets live rates every minute, or the one that makes importjson to update or other things that I have been searching during the last months

Comment: @Alex Can't help you if you don't show your attempts at script. It doesn't need to be working. All we need is [mcve]: your attempt, and the error it throws. Ask a new question for the first error and go from there... Second error?  Can't fix it? Ask a new question again with [mcve]. As of now, your question is way too broad and you're highly unlikely to get what you want.

Comment: Well, this is what I was able to do so far. a custom function that compare what I need to compare and returns the result but. it gives me this error:

Service invoked too many times in a short time: exec qps. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls. (line 0).

and it blocks my spreadsheet. and when it finally gives the result for all the signals, it updates everytime the price updates even after having reached the result